fraction not display instead down a line
I am using Visual Studio 2022 I tried to display on the screen a fraction in math the code is
"\frac{ 2}{ 6}" but the vs2022 color only the "\f"
and instead of writing a fraction it down a line
thanks for your listening
or
I write code in c# vs2022
I wrote in the code exp7.Text ="\frac{ 2}{ 6}"
to write a fraction but instead he downline.
what should i do?

I do'nt want it as a string I want it as a fraction such 1\2 as half.

Since basckslash is an escaping character, you need to double it in order to create a string containing a backslash, as you would do with double quotes .
exp7.Text = "\\frac{ 2}{ 6}"


I try that but it does not write a fraction.

It print -\frac{ 2}{ 6}. on the screen

Then it is a problem with the math library you use, not with visual studio, you may want to add the name of that library as a tag, and in the question body
